# There is no QRCode on terminal when type npm start

Tags: react-native

I type command `create-react-native-app <My package name>`

then i type `npm start` i can see QRCode shows on my terminal

But when i type `npm run eject` for my project

I type `npm start` again. There's no QRCode show on my terminal any more.
[image]

I looking for some answer still can't fix it. It confused with me a lot.

Here is my environment:
Mac OS:10.13.4

```
{
  "name": "TestMovie2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@shoutem/animation": "^0.12.2",
    "@shoutem/ui": "^0.23.4",
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: ```eject``` takes you out of the Expo world (and the Expo app with QR scanner). You now have a "pure" react-native app that no long runs in the Expo app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if i want to run my project on real device convenient, may be i should use Expo ide to create my project ?

Comment: Not necessary. Use react native cli commands. ```react-native run-ios``` will run it on the simulator without opening Xcode. In the future don't eject unless you really have to.

Comment: In other words, if run it on real device , just plug in USB to development machine and type comman `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android` right ? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Hope you have solved the problem , but anyone still facing the problem can just type **expo start** instead of npm start

Comment: This should be updated in the react native docs. I'd upvote 10 times if I could. Thanks.